# Integration Java to salesforce

Tags: integration, java

I am new of INTEGRATION. So please help me.

I have a Java Program, Now i need to integrate this program to Salesforce?

Java Code:

```
public class abc {
public void a()
{
  int a=20,b=30;
  int c=a+b;
  System.out.println("The Value is:"+c);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   abc test = new abc();
  test.a(); 
}
```

Now i need to connect this Java programme to Salesforce through Integration?

Comment: I suggest you be more explicit about where the Java code is running, what functionality it provides (the code you have included looking entirely contrived), and why you need to access it from Salesforce (or need it to access Salesforce). Your question is too broad at present to be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

If not through middleware integration is commonly done through the SOAP or REST API webservices exposed by salesforce. You will need to learn how to do this from Java, but that is not salesforce specific and better asked on stackoverflow of java specific fora.

In terms of salesforce integration, these are a few references:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integration

[SOAP API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/)

[REST API documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/)

[Force.com webservice connector (java)](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector)

Comment: Good summary given the scope of the question, i'd perhaps add one more useful link for Java devs, that is the Salesforce Web Service connector. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector

Comment: That is indeed a useful addition, I've added it in. Thanks

Comment: @user5564 check this link http://www.dhruvsoft.com/blog/creating-custom-apex-soap-based-on-web-services-in-salesforce-com-and-accessing-from-java-application/